# Python Crash Course: Including if statement inside a for loop in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, nested-for-loop, logic-error

I'm new to Python and just started learning Python at the end of January. I'm currently on page 110 of Python Crash Course (Chapter 6: Dictionaries). In the favorites languages program, I try to include an if statement inside of a dictionary's for loop to see each user has more than one favorite language with len(languages) method, then produce different results based on the user's number of languages. Here my code and the result:

```py
**favorite_languages = {
    'jen': ['python','c'],
    'lucas': ['python'],
    'veronica': ['c','ruby'],
    'jack': ['haskel','go'],
    }
for name, languages in favorite_languages.items():
    if len(languages) == 1:
        print(f"\n{name.title()}'s favorite language is : {language.title()}")
    else:
        print(f"\n{name.title()}'s favorite languages are: ")
        for language in languages:
            print(f"\t{language.title()}")**
```

I expected the result that if the user has a single favorite language, the code will print out:

```
    "{user}'s favorite language is : {language.title()},
```

or else:

```
    "{user}'s favorite languages are: {language.title()}"
```

And here is the result:

```
Jen's favorite languages are: 
    Python
    C

Lucas's favorite language is : C

Veronica's favorite languages are: 
    C
    Ruby

Jack's favorite languages are: 
    Haskel
    Go
```

As far as I concerned, the code runs well, except that in Lucas's favorite language result was different. The result said Lucas's favorite language is C instead of Python like I wrote it in the program.

I would appreciate it if anyone helps me out on this.

Comment: So what result did you get and what was the result you expected to get?

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself as text. Screenshots of code are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi! I fixed the post and add more detail about the question. I will pay more attention next time. And I'm still working out to find the solution. Thank you for reaching out.

Answer (score 3):

The only place you defined `language` - singular - is when you loop through each language of someone who likes multiple languages. If Lucas had been the first in the list, it would've produced an error. As it is, `language` at that point was still on Jen's latest favorite of C. To fix this, use `languages[0]` when checking for a single favorite language.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Correct code:

```
**favorite_languages = {
    'jen': ['python', 'ruby'],
    'sarah': ['c'],
    'edward': ['ruby', 'go'],
    'phil': ['python', 'haskell'],
}

for name, languages in favorite_languages.items():
    if len(languages[0]) == 1:
        print(f"\n{name.title()}'s favorite language is ")
    else:
        print(f"\n{name.title()}'s favorite language are: ")
    for language in languages:
        print(f"\t{language.title()}")**
```

Thanks everyone!